# Ruby code to get size in bytes of a webpage

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nokogiri, page-size

I want to calculate the size in bytes of a webpage, like www.google.com has around 44kb size, facebook.com has around 17k. I have tried Nokogiri to calculate the HTML's length but it gives 8k for Google and 32k for Facebook. I don't want to use any third-party tool, I want to calculate it in my application.

Comment: If the HTML is/can be sent gzipped over the 'net, do you want the size of the gzipped data, or the raw uncompressed size from the response?

Comment: Nokogiri is NOT the tool to use for this. It's an XML/HTML parser only.

Answer (score 3):

This code sample should get you on your way. It downloads the site, and uses the length method to retrieve the size.

```
require 'net/http'
require 'fileutils' #I'm pretty sure this is needed for the delete method  
  class HttpSample  
  def downloadGoogleHome  
    proxy = Net::HTTP::Proxy('ipaddress', portnumber) # use actual ip and port  
    url = URI.parse('http://www.google.com')  
    http_response = proxy.get_response(url) 
    puts http_response.body.length #size
  end
  s = HttpSample.new  
  s.downloadGoogleHome  
end
```

Comment: There's no need to save something to a file. You can get the size of the retrieved data in bytes with the `http_response.body.length` method.

Comment: Do you want the size of all the html, frames, subframes, images, css and js used by the page, or just the html?

Comment: @paperids I tried your code, but its not working for me..It gives zero

Comment: @paperids what do i enter in the portnumber part

Comment: The port number should in this case be HTTP->80.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Net::HTTP::Head` allows you to ask the server about a page without it having to return the page and waste their, and your, bandwidth and CPU time. One of the headers returned should be the `Content-Length`:

```
require 'net/http'
request = Net::HTTP.new('google.com', 80)
head = request.request_head('/')
```

returns:

```
#<Net::HTTPMovedPermanently:0x102157ae0
    @body_exist = false,
    @read = true,
    @socket = nil,
    attr_accessor :body = nil,
    attr_reader :code = "301",
    attr_reader :header = {
                "location" => [
            [0] "http://www.google.com/"
        ],
            "content-type" => [
            [0] "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
        ],
                    "date" => [
            [0] "Thu, 26 Jul 2012 17:46:30 GMT"
        ],
                 "expires" => [
            [0] "Sat, 25 Aug 2012 17:46:30 GMT"
        ],
           "cache-control" => [
            [0] "public, max-age=2592000"
        ],
                  "server" => [
            [0] "gws"
        ],
          "content-length" => [
            [0] "219"
        ],
        "x-xss-protection" => [
            [0] "1; mode=block"
        ],
         "x-frame-options" => [
            [0] "SAMEORIGIN"
        ],
              "connection" => [
            [0] "close"
        ]
    },
    attr_reader :http_version = "1.1",
    attr_reader :message = "Moved Permanently"
>
```

That's a redirect, showing the browser needs to look elsewhere.

Unfortunately, not all HTTPd return the `content-length` header, because the page might be created dynamically, so it can't make a good guess until the content has actually been rendered and sent.

Following the redirection above with another HEAD request results in:

```
#<Net::HTTPOK:0x10217e8c0
    @body_exist = false,
    @read = true,
    @socket = nil,
    attr_accessor :body = nil,
    attr_reader :code = "200",
    attr_reader :header = {
              "set-cookie" => [
            [ 0] "NID=62=c2jRl25ItoF5YkVgNv3g2woB2A3iIqkY__EYX5BGst--KYmjNbfCeVL0FIUcq6jm6PqH_-YV6QFO_yNjy1BzMms-QJKPRsfcq0px030WVzKTMtMF9dJUJpS0XdV1NLOv; expires=Fri, 25-Jan-2013 17:50:22 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly",
            [ 1] "expires=; expires=Mon, 01-Jan-1990 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; domain=www.google.com",
            [ 2] "path=; expires=Mon, 01-Jan-1990 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; domain=www.google.com",
            [ 3] "domain=; expires=Mon, 01-Jan-1990 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; domain=www.google.com",
            [ 4] "expires=; expires=Mon, 01-Jan-1990 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; domain=www.google.com",
            [ 5] "path=; expires=Mon, 01-Jan-1990 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; domain=www.google.com",
            [ 6] "domain=; expires=Mon, 01-Jan-1990 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; domain=www.google.com",
            [ 7] "expires=; expires=Mon, 01-Jan-1990 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; domain=.www.google.com",
            [ 8] "path=; expires=Mon, 01-Jan-1990 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; domain=.www.google.com",
            [ 9] "domain=; expires=Mon, 01-Jan-1990 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; domain=.www.google.com",
            [10] "expires=; expires=Mon, 01-Jan-1990 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; domain=.www.google.com",
            [11] "path=; expires=Mon, 01-Jan-1990 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; domain=.www.google.com",
            [12] "domain=; expires=Mon, 01-Jan-1990 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; domain=.www.google.com",
            [13] "expires=; expires=Mon, 01-Jan-1990 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; domain=google.com",
            [14] "path=; expires=Mon, 01-Jan-1990 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; domain=google.com",
            [15] "domain=; expires=Mon, 01-Jan-1990 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; domain=google.com",
            [16] "expires=; expires=Mon, 01-Jan-1990 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; domain=google.com",
            [17] "path=; expires=Mon, 01-Jan-1990 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; domain=google.com",
            [18] "domain=; expires=Mon, 01-Jan-1990 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; domain=google.com",
            [19] "expires=; expires=Mon, 01-Jan-1990 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com",
            [20] "path=; expires=Mon, 01-Jan-1990 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com",
            [21] "domain=; expires=Mon, 01-Jan-1990 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com",
            [22] "expires=; expires=Mon, 01-Jan-1990 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com",
            [23] "path=; expires=Mon, 01-Jan-1990 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com",
            [24] "domain=; expires=Mon, 01-Jan-1990 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com",
            [25] "PREF=ID=51ce2f15ffbc5de1:FF=0:TM=1343325022:LM=1343325022:S=H8-1NoxuEbX7fepF; expires=Sat, 26-Jul-2014 17:50:22 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com",
            [26] "NID=62=aO6oBKx_v48l5SqQrRDUiNxfOixEE0QnkQIBSZK4u0xS8cHGc7uXTUt6yJhIZTyCe_XWGn6t3-Ov4EvxPE8hAO7I89ao9RR9dLUyYPBB784fR12bJsqbkTaCVaZI7ihT; expires=Fri, 25-Jan-2013 17:50:22 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly"
        ],
                    "date" => [
            [0] "Thu, 26 Jul 2012 17:50:22 GMT"
        ],
                 "expires" => [
            [0] "-1"
        ],
           "cache-control" => [
            [0] "private, max-age=0"
        ],
            "content-type" => [
            [0] "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        ],
                     "p3p" => [
            [0] "CP=\"This is not a P3P policy! See http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151657 for more info.\""
        ],
                  "server" => [
            [0] "gws"
        ],
        "x-xss-protection" => [
            [0] "1; mode=block"
        ],
         "x-frame-options" => [
            [0] "SAMEORIGIN"
        ],
              "connection" => [
            [0] "close"
        ]
    },
    attr_reader :http_version = "1.1",
    attr_reader :message = "OK"
>
```

Notice, no `content-length` header was returned.

Going to a site that returns a static page gives me a different response:

```
request = Net::HTTP.new('tools.ietf.org', 80)
head = request.request_head('/html/rfc2606')
```

returns:

```
#<Net::HTTPOK:0x100914370
    @body_exist = false,
    @read = true,
    @socket = nil,
    attr_accessor :body = nil,
    attr_reader :code = "200",
    attr_reader :header = {
                    "date" => [
            [0] "Thu, 26 Jul 2012 17:55:23 GMT"
        ],
                  "server" => [
            [0] "Apache/2.2.21 (Debian)"
        ],
        "content-location" => [
            [0] "rfc2606.html"
        ],
                    "vary" => [
            [0] "negotiate"
        ],
                     "tcn" => [
            [0] "choice"
        ],
           "last-modified" => [
            [0] "Sat, 26 May 2012 22:18:00 GMT"
        ],
                    "etag" => [
            [0] "\"d44ff-43da-4c0f7db90d600;4c5bf43471540\""
        ],
           "accept-ranges" => [
            [0] "bytes"
        ],
          "content-length" => [
            [0] "17370"
        ],
              "connection" => [
            [0] "close"
        ],
            "content-type" => [
            [0] "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
        ]
    },
    attr_reader :http_version = "1.1",
    attr_reader :message = "OK"
>
```

So, yes, it's possible to tell, but sometimes you can't get the needed information from the `HEAD` request.

In the past, my way to work around that was to try the HEAD first, and if that didn't give me what I needed, then I'd retrieve the page using a normal GET, then take the size from it. It helped reduce wasted bandwidth taking that approach.